# SXA rendering variants fallback

Tags: sxa

Does anyone know exactly how the fallback works on rendering variants in SXA? 
I was checking the default variant of the navigation, and I can see:

- Navigation title

  - Title
  - __Display name

I assumed that the `navigation title` is used if present. Which seems to be correct. And I think it fallbacks to `title` as that is it's child.. which also seems to work. But what is the `display name` doing there? Based on the item definitions I would expect the `display name` to be rendered after the `title` in case we have no `navigation title`.. but that is not the case. I see in the rendered html that the `display name` is rendered as title-attribute of the link on my `title` (or `navigation title`).

So, why is it rendering this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting will have different behavior, depending on which variant field you select. The most popular field used to wrap something is `Section`

For `VariantField` if you nest another `VariantField` it will work like a fallback for the parent.

If parent field is empty then first child will be taken as a fallback value. If first child is also missing, then second and so on.

- `Variant Definition`

  - `VariantField1`

    - `VariantField2` - first fallback for `VariantField1`
    - `VariantField3` - second fallback for `VariantField1` (if `VariantField2` empty)

So nested variant fields are used to define fallback values only.

#### Why you see `Display name` as a title attribute?

Because it is hard-coded in code `RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.cs`

`CreateHyperLink` call

```
if (customField is FileField)
{
    FileField fileField = item.Fields[linkFieldName];
    string fileUrl = fileField.MediaItem != null ? MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(fileField.MediaItem) : string.Empty;
    return CreateHyperLink(fileUrl, item.DisplayName, isDownloadLink, attributes);
}
```

`CreateHyperLink`

```
protected virtual HyperLink CreateHyperLink(string href, string title, bool isDownloadLink, NameValueCollection attributes)
{
    HyperLink hpl = new HyperLink();
    hpl.Attributes["title"] = title;
```

#### Solution

If this is a huge problem, you can fix it.

1. Create derived type of `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField` class
2. Override `CreateHyperLink` method with your logic
3. Replace old implementation with your by patching configuration file

pipeline:

`renderVariantField`

processor

```
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.config"/>`
```

Comment: Ah, ok.. it's the hard-coded part that got me confused. Didn't expect anything in sxa to be hard-coded :)  But so it's actually working as I expected.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it's hard coded - we just defined such attribute value. But in SXA you can override everything:)