# Map a rendering variant field with two template fields

Tags: sxa

I got a scenario that if a template value is empty(e.g Title),same rendering variant field should render with another template field(e.g description.).
Is there a way to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is considered a VariantField fallback.

Should look something like this:

[image: Example]

[Community post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/5819/95)

[Official docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/enable-field-fallback-functionality.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you have currently defined the variants for Title and Description, but one solution would be to have the two variant fields inside a single variant and then control how they are displayed by using Rules. There is a `Rule` field on variant fields (depending on the SXA version that you are using) that you can use to show/hide different sections.

[image]